# Apps doesn't show Documentation reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, android-app, ios-app

The dialog containing recent reputation in the Android and iOS app doesn't show the changes of the reputation due to activities in the new Stack Overflow Documentation.

Comment: The api correctly expose those events https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history#ids=792066&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: @Braiam it appears it does, there are "example upvoted" events in your link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in 1.6.5.4.

Achievements in the app now match top-bar achievements.